# Bib Code for Reference

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to cite this website: https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/semiconductors/our-insights/the-semiconductor-decade-a-trillion-dollar-industry

Then, use this code for the bib file.

```
@misc{mckinsey__2022,
    title = {The semiconductor decade: A trillion-dollar industry},
    url = {https://www.mckinsey.com/industries/semiconductors/our-insights/the-semiconductor-decade-a-trillion-dollar-industry},
    urldate = {2022-04-01},
    author = {McKinsey \& Company},
    year = {2022},
}
```

I use the following code for the reference in overleaf

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\bibliography{centralbib.bib}

\end{document}
```

However the result is :
[image: screenshot]

Here is the expected visual, the word McKinsey appears on the reference.

[image: expected]

Is there any way to do so? Or, is it the overleaf rule?

Comment: I can't test it now, but I assume that "McKinsey &" is treated as the given name and therefore abbreviated by "M." Maybe try wrapping the author in curly braces, i.e. `author = {{McKinsey \& Company}}`.

Comment: Hi @Οὖτις, it works! thank you!